# How to increment Id column from 1 each time when new data added to database

Tags: mysql

I want to increment id column in table always from one whenever data newly added to database table. What query should I use?

Comment: `AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: What you think what it should do?

Comment: your question and your comment are not clear try explain better ..

Comment: I am sending data from java to MySQL table. Now, for first time when i execute project id field start from 1 and for second time it start from next value where it stop earlier because of auto increment. I want to make it start from 1 each time when i execute my project.

Comment: @RohanKalyankar do you want your previous data to be retained?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete previous data and then reset AUTO_INCREMENT field you need to execute:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```